# Symfony2 Security log user manually

Tags: security, symfony, logging, fosuserbundle

I want to log user manually in Symfony2. (I use fosuserbundle).
The authentication will be triggered in custom route like this /login/auto

Here is my controller code which match with /login/auto

```
public function loginAction(){

        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $users = $em->getRepository('MybundleMainBundle:User');
        $user = $users->findOneByEmail("user@user.com");

        $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
        $securityContext->setToken($token);
        $this->get('session')->set('_security_'.'main', serialize($token));


        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('home')); 
}
```

But after the redirection, I'm redirected automatically to /login and not /home so the authentification failed

Here is my security file config :

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            switch_user: true
            remember_me:
                key:    %secret%
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:     ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does the dev.log say?

Answer (score 1):

Looks very similar to mine. Maybe you should not write into the session. Or the token needs the (hashed) password. Try it, here's a working code ;)

```
public function demologinAction(Request $request)
{
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
    $repo = $dm->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:User');
    $user = $repo->findOneByUsername('demo');

    if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No demouser found!');
    }

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main', $user->getRoles());

    $context = $this->get('security.context');
    $context->setToken($token);

    $router = $this->get('router');
    $url = $router->generate('dashboard_show');

    return $this->redirect($url);
}
```

Comment: Hi, is still not working, I think I have a problem with my security.yml and the firewall config..

Comment: The problem is after the redirection, I lose the authentication but before it works

Comment: You need to authenticate the token instead of simly setting it. You can read about it in the [Symfony2 Documentation on Authentication](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html).

Comment: Is this implementation doesn't have password check or I miss something?

Comment: Why it should? ;) No it is for programmatic login, like a demo account or directly after a special signup method (affiliate email, whatever) without password. It is not for regular login of a user.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to log a user in manually?

I may be wrong, but if the reason is so that you can run some postLogin code, it would be easier to use the built in login functionality, but setup a listener on the login action as a service. Then add your login code in there.

Sevice definition would be:

```
user.login:
    class: You\Bundle\EventListener\EventListener
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @service_container]
    tags:
          - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onLogin }
```

And your event listener might be:

```
public function onLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
    $user->setLastLoggedInAt(new \DateTime());
    $user->setLoginCount($user->getLoginCount() + 1);

    $this->manager->flush();
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a demo user, like I do. Log in the user with a simple link, like a normal user.

Comment: I just think it's a good idea to avoid trying to hack the login system if it can be avoided.

Comment: Yes, but a demo user is not really a hack into the login system.

Comment: I want to do that because I want to allow user to log in with Google oauth2. I use Google API to fetch user's email. If this email belong to my user list, I want to log the user manually. 

I do that into this route : /login/auto. 

When I log manually the user, it works on this route /login/auto but when I redirect the user in the "home" he is redirected to /login automatically

I hope you will understand my problem

Jon, I will test your solution tomorrow

Thanks again for your help